# Objective c countOfBytesReceived over countOfBytesExpectedToReceive returns 0.000000

Tags: ios, objective-c, integer-division

I am trying to work out `countOfBytesReceived / countOfBytesExpectedToReceive` but it either returns `0.000000` or `1.000000`.

I did an `NSLog` on both `countOfBytesReceived` and `countOfBytesExpectedToReceive` I can see the `countOfBytesExpectedToReceive` remains the same as expected and `countOfBytesReceived` changes.

```
CGFloat progressRatio = [task countOfBytesReceived] / [task countOfBytesExpectedToReceive];

[progressView setProgress:progressRatio];

NSLog(@"%lld", [task countOfBytesReceived]);
NSLog(@"%lld", [task countOfBytesExpectedToReceive]);
NSLog(@"%f)", progressRatio);
```

but `progressRatio` always returns `0.000000` or `1.000000` when it shouldn't.

I have this code in a `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` so its does run every 0.01.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because progressRatio is calculated dividing two integer values. In C when you divide two integers you get an integer. That is. Add a casting to get a float:

```
CGFloat progressRatio = (CGFloat) [task countOfBytesReceived] / (CGFloat )[task countOfBytesExpectedToReceive];
```

Answer (score 1):

`countOfBytesRecieved` and `countOfBytesExpectedToReceive` are both 64-bit integers. C expression evaluation will promote either the left or right arguments of a binary expression to the most compatible type.

`(int64_t)a / (int64_t)b`

But since both sides of this expression are 64-bit integers, no conversion is necessary and it performs integer math. Given the nature of these values, the result will be `0` (if the a < b) or `1` (if a == b).

C then evaluates the next expression:

`(float)ratio = (int64_t)n`

Since this is an assignment, it must convert the integer (`1` or `0`) into a floating point value (`1.0` or `0.0`).

If you want to perform floating point division, force C to convert the original integers into floating point values *first*:

```
CGFloat progressRatio = (CGFloat)[task countOfBytesReceived] / (CGFloat)[task countOfBytesExpectedToReceive];
```